# Mostrar 100 primeros números en filas de 10 y que cada fila sea de un color

Tags: php

Estoy aprendiendo PHP y tengo el siguiente ejercicio:

**Mostrar en pantalla una tabla de 10 por 10 con los números del 1 al 100, haz uso de variables, pero colorear las filas alternando colores, además el tamaño de la tabla será una constante: define(TAM, 10).**

Lo tengo hecho pero me falta la parte de alternar las filas de un color (por ejemplo, rojo) y el siguiente negro otra vez. Este es el código que llevo:

```
<?php

define("TAM", 10);
$Color = "red";
$Color2 = "black";

for( $i=1; $i<=100; $i++ ){    
    echo $i;
    echo " ";
    if($i%TAM==0){
     echo '<div style="Color:'.$Color.'"</div>';}
}
    
    ?>
```

Eso me imprime los números del 1 al 100 en filas de 10 pero a partir de la segunda fila sale todo en rojo, ¿alguna ayuda para poner una fila de color rojo y la siguiente del color normal? ¡Gracias!

Al ejecutarlo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te están pidiendo una _tabla_, supongo que deberías usar las etiquetas adecuadas en lugar de _div_. Probablemente solo necesites un contador para incrementar las filas e intercalar color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que siempre imprimes un `<div style="color:red"></div>` una vez pasando la primera iteración, para eso tendría que alternar entre los colores de acuerdo a la fila en la que te encuentres

```
<?php

define("TAM", 10);
$Color = "red";
$Color2 = "black";
$row = 0;
for( $i=1; $i<=100; $i++ ){    
    echo $i;
    echo " ";
    if($i%TAM==0){
        echo '<div style="Color:'.($row%2 == 0 ? $Color: $Color2).'"</div>';
        $row++;
    }
}
```

En este código, `$row` se saca el residuo y si es igual a 0, imprimirá el color Rojo, de lo contrario el color negro, por eso alterna

NOTA.

Hay cosas que se podrían mejorar en el código.

Primeramente, las variables son recomendables que vayan con minúscula, por lo que deberías cambiar `$Color` por `$color`, y `$Color2` por '$color2'

En segunda estás solo dividiendo las lineas con un div, y queda mejor si los datos están dentro de ese div

```
<?php

define("TAM", 10);
$color = "red";
$color2 = "black";
$row = 0;
$new_row = true;
for( $i=1; $i<=100; $i++ ){
    if($new_row){
        echo '<div style="Color:'.($row%2 != 0 ? $color: $color2).'">';
        $new_row = false;
    }
    echo $i;
    echo " ";
    if($i%TAM==0){
        echo '</div>';
        $row++;
        $new_row = true;
    }
}
```

Por lo que este código hace lo mismo que el primero, pero a nivel de HTML queda mejor estructurado.